# On the relations between Graph Theory and Algebra

Tags: graph-theory

Below I quote two paragraphs I need your help on.

I keep on reading on the mathematical structures of language, where some authors like Zellig Harris come to analogies (and more than analogies) like the one expressed in the first paragraph I am interested in:

“There are various types of graph which represent the relations among sentences in such a way that properties of transformations or of subsets of sentences can be derived from properties of the graph.”

Then he gets really specific in the second paragraph:

“Consider the decomposition semi-lattice of an arbitrary proposition S1.Here the vertices are operators (including the null points which select the kernel sentences, and the universal point which adds the sentence intonation); the edges connecting the vertices represent a minimal set of independent partial sentences of S1 sufficient to characterize S1. Because of the partial ordering of the transformations, some of the partial sentences of S1 do not appear in the semi-lattice. We construct a graph representing all the partial sentences of S1, i.e., all the sentences which can be obtained in the course of any order of decomposition of S1, as follows: each operator vertex of the semi-lattice is replaced by an element consisting of a directed edge (representing the operator) from the end point of the preceding element, and a terminal vertex (which represents the resultant partial sentence); except that the null point is replaced by a vertex alone, and the universal point is replaced by nothing; in addition, each set of n lattice points which are unordered among themselves is replaced by 2n2 vertices representing all the sentences that can be formed by combinations of the n operators from 1 up to n  1 at a time (we draw connecting edges first for each pair, the for each triple, and so on, up to n-tuple of the n points; each set of connecting edges ends in a vertex representing the partial sentence).”

My questions are:

1) What kind of theorem allows for the transition from the properties of graphs to those of an algebraic nature (bijective applications; partial ordering, subsets, and the like) which hold between elements of the language (sentences, parts of sentences)?

2) What is the exact mathematical nature of the graph described in the second paragraph? What specific laws translate its graph features to the languagelike properties mentioned there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a clarification comment for those of you no familiar at all with linguistics. A transformation in that context ist something of the kind of a pasive voice transformation which yields, from an initial kernel sentence like "Peter bought th house", the result "The house was bought by Peter". Of course, many subtransformations play a role there, but you can ignore that..